# Add id attributes to developer story sections

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

I'm pretty fond of the Developer Story's Recommended Reading component and would like to link to it directly. Rather than maintaining another list elsewhere, I would only need to update it in one place. A direct link also feels less disingenuous than having someone else scroll past my entire story to find it (the ideal would be to keep it separate but composable with the story, but that's a harder and more selfish request).

I figure the easiest implementation would be to add an id attribute for use with a URL fragment but that's not my prerogative so I'd be happy with anything that achieves a comparable effect. Although I'm only interested in linking to the readings section, I believe it's fair to generalize and hence the plural in the title request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How do I have users open my developer story to my project or reading?

On your developer story, each item has an id as shown in the example below. You would select your recommended reading that would be on the bottom of your developer story.

You can copy its id by selecting it with your developer tools.

> **Tip**: There is usually a button on the top left that you can click to have your cursor guide you to the element. Click on an element to
> select it in your DOM viewer.

You can add a `#` followed by the id, to the end of your developer story's URL, to have visitors open your story scrolled to that element.

Comment: This is embarrassing, I could've sworn I was thorough in my checking but I missed the id attribute of the containing div for the reading section. Thanks for your help.